# Handling Multiple File Inputs in React Using useRef Array Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, file-upload

I am working on a React application where I am dynamically rendering multiple file input elements using the Swiper component and Dropzone. However, when I attempt to gather all the files selected by these inputs during form submission, I consistently get undefined.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

My Home component:

```
const Home = () => {
  const fileInputRefs = useRef<React.RefObject<HTMLInputElement>[]>([]);
  //...other hooks and useEffects

  const handleSubmit = async () => {
    const filesToUpload = fileInputRefs.current.map(
      (ref) => ref.current?.files?.[0]
    );
    for (let i = 0; i < filesToUpload.length; i++) {
      const fileToUpload = filesToUpload[i];
      console.log(`Selected file from input ${i}:`, fileToUpload);
      //...rest of the code for upload
    }
  };
  //...other methods and render
};
```

My SwiperComponent:

```
  //...hooks and methods

  const slides = images.map((image, index) => /*...*/);

  for (let i = images.length; i < 10; i++) {
    const ref = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>();
    if (fileInputRefs.current) {
      fileInputRefs.current.push(ref);
    }
    slides.push(
      <SwiperSlide key={i}>
        <Dropzone
          onDrop={onDrop}
          setFiles={setFiles}
          ref={fileInputRefs[i]}
        />
      </SwiperSlide>
    );
  }
  //...render
};
```

My Dropzone:

```
  ({ onDrop, setFiles }, ref) => {
    const handleFileInput = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      if (event.target.files) {
        const filesArray = Array.from(event.target.files);
        onDrop(filesArray);
        setFiles(filesArray);
      }
    };
    //...other methods and render
  }
);
```

The console output always prints Selected file from input X: undefined for each input. It seems like the file inputs are not correctly populated with the selected files. Can anyone spot what I might be doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a problem with the way you store and handle refs for your components. `fileInputRefs.current.push(ref)` seems to be adding more elements to the array every rerender

Comment: Thanks @veelon yes, this is adding 111 files, all undefined, but I only have 10 input sliders. No idea how to fix it though.